# Measure current in power suppy

Tags: power-supply, resistors, current-measurement, sensing

I have a power supply which I ordered online for 100 amps. I thought it will be digital but its an old fashioned type. I want to build the current sensing circuit to find out how much current is coming from the power supply. I don't have the multimeter to measure 100 amps. So please any one can guide me how to build the current sensing circuit and there specifications for resistor used.

Thank you.

Comment: Your post reveals a misunderstanding regarding how voltage, current, and load work.  The 100A of current that you refer to could be at 1.7V for all we know.  You will have to load the power supply with a load that will draw 100A before you can think about measuring.  Post a datasheet or model number and we can help guide you to the right place.

Comment: What resistor? I suggest you check out [how current sensors are made](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_sensor#Technologies)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to use a high current shunt resistor.  There are commercially available units.  Just google "high current shunts". A typical device is rated at 500 amps and 75 millivolts.  At 100 amps, this shunt would generate 15 millivolts (and dissipate 1.5 watts). You could use a multimeter to measure the voltage drop directly (most have a low voltage range of 200 millivolts or so). If you need more resolution of the current, you could use a shunt with a larger voltage drop (which would also dissipate more power).

Answer (score 0):

You can likely get a 100A shunt from an electronics hobby store (my local go-to has both the shunts and some digital meters to suit them). Failing that, eBay has more current shunts than you could ever need, I've seen ones for sale from 0-1A up to 0-1500A and everything in-between.